# Using arrays in C (error in the output)

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I had this task :

Given the following array, write a program that reverses all array elements then prints them.
int x[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

then i wrote that code :

```
int main()    {    
  int x[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  int y[10] ;
  int i;
  i=0 ;

  for(i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)   {    
    x[i]=y[9-i] ;
  }

  printf("\r\n The reversed array is : \r\n{ ") ;

  i=0 ;
  for(i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)  {    
    printf("%d \t ,",y[i] ) ;
  }
  printf("}") ;

  return(0) ;
}
```

and the output was this

[image: d]

what is wrong with the code ?

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Try `y[i] = x[9-i];`

Comment: http://imgur.com/uvDOADL

Comment: Please fix your keyboard. Your <CR> seems stuck.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Nobody ever needs to see a screenshot of text.

Comment: it worked ,, thanks alot :D

Comment: I think this should be closed because it's caused by **a simple typographical error**.

Comment: i'm kinda new here .. thanks for help

Comment: don't print `\r\n`. Just use `\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

`x[i]=y[9-i] ;`

You are assigning to `x`; however, `x` is your input data. The `y` array is uninitialized, so when you assign values from it to `x`, you get garbage data. This is why generic variable names like `x` and `y` are generally discouraged; it's easy to mix them up and make mistakes like this.

Anyway, if you switch that around, and assign the values from `x` to `y` instead, it should fix your problem.